# jquery custom, customize attr

Tags: jquery, unwrap

My coding wordpress loop menu. Is possible replace JQ?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 1st Loop -->
<li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle='dropdown' class='dropdown-toggle'  href='javascript:void(0);' >First Pages</a>
    <!-- Should be
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse-firstpage">First Page</a>
    -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- Should be
    <ul id="collapse-firstpage" class="collapse">
    -->
        <li><a href="new-page-1">New Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="new-page-2">New Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- End 1st Loop -->
```

on href record the title (First Page to firstpage), insert [#collapse-] before and on ul id same like href but without [#].

Comment: yes this is possible

Comment: Can help me, Thanks

Comment: Auto remove space and lowercase

Comment: wait i will put my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use each loop

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.dropdown').each(function(){
var  $val = $(this).children('a').html();
var $page_name = $val.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').split(' ').join('');
$(this).children('a').replaceWith(' <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse-'+$page_name+'">'+$val+'</a>');
$('.collapse', this).attr('id','collapse-'+$page_name);
})
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 1st Loop -->
<li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle='dropdown' class='dropdown-toggle'  href='javascript:void(0);' >First Pages</a>
    <!-- Should be
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse-firstpage">First Page</a>
    -->
    <ul class="collapse">
    <!-- Should be
    <ul id="collapse-firstpage" class="collapse">
    -->
        <li><a href="new-page-1">New Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="new-page-2">New Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- End 1st Loop -->
```

jQuery

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.dropdown').each(function(){
var  $val = $(this).children('a').html();
var $page_name = $val.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').split(' ').join('');
$(this).children('a').replaceWith(' <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse-'+$page_name+'">'+$val+'</a>');
$('.collapse', this).attr('id','collapse-'+$page_name);
})
 });
```

Comment: if you need more help then tell me

Comment: maybe not with +$page_name

Comment: can u please explain me what i putted wrong there and what u actually need there

Comment: you html like is <li class="myclass"><a href="blabla">Test</a></li>

Comment: and you need like <li class="myclass">Test</li> , am i right?

Comment: can you please check in my code $('.collapse', this).attr('id','#collapse-'+$page_name);, this code work is <ul class="dropdown-menu"> should be <ul id="collapse-firstpage" class="collapse">

Comment: sorry please provide proper url of your site

Comment: Suresh Suthar your Anwers is correct, Great, thank alot

Comment: I am Newbie on stackovr, click up arrow? where i can do?

Comment: https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/866997/g27re6tnqps9kuq912q9

Comment: i need up reputation,i was click but back to 0, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow